# Angular 2 Datatable expandable row with custom html binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I'm trying to use data table and have the ability to have an extended child row while clicking on the + it will expend the row and display additional data with some buttons binding this is the ajax version before moving to angular 2 :[image]

each row a child row for additional actions and info.

Here is the component :

```
import {Component, Input, ElementRef, AfterContentInit, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({

  selector: 'sa-datatable',
  template: `
      <table class="dataTable {{tableClass}}" width="{{width}}">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </table>
`,
  styles: [
    require('smartadmin-plugins/datatables-bundle/datatables.min.css')
  ]
})
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public options:any;
  @Input() public filter:any;
  @Input() public detailsFormat:any;

  @Input() public paginationLength: boolean;
  @Input() public columnsHide: boolean;
  @Input() public tableClass: string;
  @Input() public width: string = '100%';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    Promise.all([
      System.import('script-loader!smartadmin-plugins/datatables-bundle/datatables.min.js'),
    ]).then(()=>{
      this.render()

    })
  }

  render() {
    let element = $(this.el.nativeElement.children[0]);
    let options = this.options || {}


    let toolbar = '';
    if (options.buttons)
      toolbar += 'B';
    if (this.paginationLength)
      toolbar += 'l';
    if (this.columnsHide)
      toolbar += 'C';

    if (typeof options.ajax === 'string') {
      let url = options.ajax;
      options.ajax = {
        url: url,
        // complete: function (xhr) {
        //
        // }
      }
    }

    options = $.extend(options, {

      "dom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs text-right'" + toolbar + ">r>" +
      "t" +
      "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
      oLanguage: {
        "sSearch": "<span class='input-group-addon'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i></span> ",
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_"
      },
      "autoWidth": false,
      retrieve: true,
      responsive: true,
      initComplete: (settings, json)=> {
        element.parent().find('.input-sm', ).removeClass("input-sm").addClass('input-md');
      }
    });

    const _dataTable = element.DataTable(options);

    if (this.filter) {
      // Apply the filter
      element.on('keyup change', 'thead th input[type=text]', function () {
        _dataTable
          .column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
          .search(this.value)
          .draw();

      });
    }


    if (!toolbar) {
      element.parent().find(".dt-toolbar").append('<div class="text-right"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="SmartAdmin" style="width: 111px; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 10px;"></div>');
    }

    if(this.detailsFormat){
      let format = this.detailsFormat
      element.on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = _dataTable.row( tr );
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
          row.child.hide();
          tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
          row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
          tr.addClass('shown');
        }
      })
    }

  }

}
```

Here is how i use it from another component in the template html:

```
<div  class="well">

    <h1>Store Items</h1>
    <sa-datatable [options]="options"
                  [detailsFormat]="detailsFormat"
                  tableClass="display projects-table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                  width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-hide="phone"></th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Item</th>
            <th data-class="expand"><i
                    class="fa fa-fw fa-user text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>
                UUID
            </th>
            <th data-hide="phone"><i
                    class="fa fa-fw fa-phone text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>
                Item ID
            </th>
            <th>Profit</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet"><i
                    class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>
                FTP Status
            </th>            
        </tr>
        </thead>

    </sa-datatable>


</div>
```

Here is my component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {FadeInTop} from "../../../shared/animations/fade-in-top.decorator";
declare var $: any;
@FadeInTop()
@Component({
    selector: 'store-items',
    templateUrl: './store-items-datatable.html',
    styleUrls: ['./store-items-datatable.css'],
    changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class StoreItemsDatatable {


    constructor() {

    }

    public options = {       
        "ajax": 'assets/roi/items.json',
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "columns": [
            {
                "class": 'details-control',
                orderable: false,
                data: null,
                defaultContent: ''
            },
            //each line is a column
            {data: "title"},
            {data: "uuid"}, 
            {data: "status"},            
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    }

    public detailsFormat(d) {

        return `<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px">Actions:</td>
                        <td><a href='${d.generalInfo.link}' target="_blank">Go To Item</a>

                            <td>`+this.getActions(d)+`</td>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>`
    }    

    getActions(data) {
        return `

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Item to FTP</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="uploadItemToFTP" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Upload Item to FTP" (click)='someMethod()'>Upload</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
    }
}
```

detailsFormat been passed in the html template using  `[detailsFormat]="detailsFormat"`

The problem is that when press the + the method of  detailsFormat returns the additional html content but the binding for the button is not working, is there a way to render the page again after clicking on the + button that the binding to the upload button will work?

the requested end results is that `(click)='someMethod()'` will work

Answer (score 0):

We have the exact same problem.
Have you ever find a solution?

I finally solved it by doing a trick, since the detailsFormat only has the reference to the html, I create a  tag and insert the component inside the tag, and return the div to be attached to datatable. 
It is simple but not easy. works great!!

in dataTable.component, have an Input() detailComponent, which you are sending from your html page as [detailComponent]="details"

and then in where it is calling the detailsFormat do:

```
 row.child(detailComponent.location.nativeElement).show();
```

Now, in the file that has the detailFormats do below:

```
public detailFormats () {

    var componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ProjectDetailsComponent);
    var newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.id = 'detailHolder';
    var ref = componentFactory.create(this.injector, [], newNode);
    this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);
    return ref;

}
```

"YourComponent" is the component that has your html that you want to show when user clicks the + button.

if you want to pass data to the component, in the DataTable.component before row line, add:

```
(detailComponent.instance).model = row.data();
```

Similar approach to:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader